# How to convert HEX value to Decimal in HIVE HQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I've got Hive 1.1, and I'm having trouble converting a HEX value into a Decimal or BIGINT.

Using UNHEX('2BD1BCAE0501250E') should return= 3157512269357720846

But instead, I'm getting something like WingDings= +Ѽ�%

I've tried DECODE, ENCODE, BASE64...but nothing seems to be working. Has anyone else tried doing this?  Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Conv**(STRING num, int from_base, int to_base) Converts a number from a given base to another

```
   conv('2BD1BCAE0501250E', 16, 10)
```

Comment: Oh wow!  Thank you Sandeep.  This seems to be working like a charm.  I've spent too many hours coming up with a work around and this was short and sweet.  Thanks again!

Comment: This doesn't work for big strings of Hex numbers. For e.g. `conv("0158419C71260101874B47D303536B7A",16,10)` and `conv("0158419B2F010101F343F8A83141C6F4",16,10)` both return  18446744073709551615.

Comment: hi Big int have limit ...u can return /store upto that no...ie BIGINT (8-byte signed integer, from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)     https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types